# How to implement POST in Web API using C# with normal URL in web browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

Basically, I am trying to make a dynamic SQL controller for Web API. I am having an issue trying to just type the normal URL path of the Web API and using the insert columns to see if I will get the data inserted successfully message but I keep getting a HTTP 405 error.

However, if I used Swagger and implemented the insert columns there, it worked. Why is that? What did I do wrong here and how can I fix this so that if I type in the web URL it would insert the data?

***Update 1:***

If I enter a breakpoint inside the function InsertData and add a URL where I use urlpath:Port/api/Main/InsertData?insertcolumns=(column1=value1)(column2=value2)(column3=value3) it wont even enter the function. On the other hand, using Swagger I entered the area where I placed the breakpoint. What could be the reason that I can't even access the function using the URL? Also if I will be using this in (say: Windows Form) how can I modify this to enter the function and get to the breakpoint?

In one file:

```
public class SQLDatabase
{
    // This class is to handle all SQL functions and they are listed below:
    // Here are the initialised variables:
    public SqlConnection DBconn = null;

    public SQLDatabase(Sqlconnection sqlConnection)
    {
        DBconn = sqlConnection.SQLconn;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function handles the execution of queries such as insert, update and delete:
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sqlquery"></param>
    public async Task<List<Dictionary<string,object>>> ExecuteSQLqueries(string basesqlquery, string tablename, string columns)
    {
        // Initialisation of the columns:
        //List<string> selectedColumns = new List<string>();
        List<object> fullresults = new List<object>();
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> results = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        string fullsqlquery;
        string selectedColumns;

        // if there are no optional columns, then get all:
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(columns))
        {
            selectedColumns = "*";
        }
        // collecting the optional columns to insert into the data 
        else
        {
            selectedColumns = columns;
        }

        // creating full sql query:
        fullsqlquery = $@"{basesqlquery} {selectedColumns} from {tablename}";

        //await DBconn.OpenAsync();
        using (SqlCommand DBcom = new SqlCommand(fullsqlquery, DBconn))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = await DBcom.ExecuteReaderAsync())
            {
                // Creating output of the queries dynamically:
                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                {
                    Dictionary<string, object> row = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                    {
                        string columnName = reader.GetName(i);
                        object columnValue = reader[i];
                        row[columnName] = columnValue;
                    }

                    results.Add(row);
                }

                return results;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function handles the execution of queries such as insert, update and delete with params:
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sqlquery"></param>
    public async Task<int> ExecuteSQLqueriesWithParams(string basesqlquery, string tablename, Dictionary<string, object> insertcolumns)
    {
        // Initialisation of the columns:
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> results = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        string fullsqlquery;
        string selectedColumns;
        string selectedColumnsValues;

        // Creating the parameters for the data to be inserted:
        selectedColumns = string.Join(", ", insertcolumns.Keys);
        selectedColumnsValues = string.Join(", ", insertcolumns.Keys.Select(key => $"@{key}"));

        // creating full sql query:
        fullsqlquery = $@"{basesqlquery} into {tablename} ({selectedColumns}) values ({selectedColumnsValues})";

        //await DBconn.OpenAsync();
        using (SqlCommand DBcom = new SqlCommand(fullsqlquery, DBconn))
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> columnskv in insertcolumns)
            {
                DBcom.Parameters.AddWithValue($"@{columnskv.Key}", columnskv.Value);
            }

            return await DBcom.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller, I have:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> InsertData(string insertcolumns)
    {
        // Obtaining the connection string:
        string jsonFilePath = jsonFilePath;
        string targetdatabase = "xxxxx";

        // Getting the Data details:
        DatabaseSettings connstr = new DatabaseSettings();
        string sqlconnecitonstring = connstr.DatabaseConnectionString(jsonFilePath, targetdatabase);
        Sqlconnection sqlconn = new Sqlconnection(sqlconnecitonstring);

        // Accessing the database:
        await sqlconn.OpenConnectionAsync();
        bool sqlconnstatus = await Task.Run(() => sqlconn.ConnectionStatus());

        if (sqlconnstatus)
        {
            // Here is the SQL query:
            string SQLQuery = "insert";

            // Splitting up the string into keys and values:
            string[] columns = insertcolumns.Split(new[] { '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Dictionary<string, object> columnsdictionary = columns.Select(item => item.Split('=')).ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => (object) s[1]);

            // Executing the Query:
            SQLDatabase sqldata = new SQLDatabase(sqlconn);
            int Data = await sqldata.ExecuteSQLqueriesWithParams(SQLQuery, tableName, columnsdictionary);

            // Closing the connection:
            sqlconn.CloseConnectionAsync();

            // Returning the output data:
            //return Ok(Data);
            return Ok("Data inserted successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            return NotFound("Database connection not successful.");
        }
    }
```

***Update 2:***

If I used the following code, it accessed the function the InsertData function but it always caused an HTTP error in the `return await DBcom.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();`. Error Code is 500 (Internal Server Error) when using following URL `urlpath:Port/api/Main/InsertData?insertcolumns=(column1=value1)(column2=value2)(column3=value3)`

```
    private async void btn_datainsert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string httprequest = HTTPrequest;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(jsonFilePath))
        {
            jsonFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        var clientbaseURL = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<urltype>(jsonFile);

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var Postdatas = $@"(data_no={data_value.Text})(datetime={DateTime.ParseExact(datetime.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + ' ' + txtbx_datetime.Text, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)})(status={Convert.ToBoolean(txtbx_databox3.Text)})";

            string fullrequest = clientbaseURL.ClientBaseURLIIS.ToString() + httprequest + "InsertData?insertcolumns=" + Postdatas;

            // Getting values inserted in textbox and use them to post data:
            //var Postdata = $@"(data_no={data_value.Text})(datetime={DateTime.ParseExact(datetime.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + ' ' + txtbx_datetime.Text, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)})(status={Convert.ToBoolean(txtbx_databox3.Text)})";
            var Postdata = new dataModel()
            {
                data_no = data_value.Text,
                txtbx_datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("M/dd/yyyy") + ' ' + txtbx_datetime.Text, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                status = Convert.ToBoolean(txtbx_databox3.Text)
            };

            var PostdataJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Postdata);
            var payLoad = new StringContent(PostdataJSON, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            using (var response = await client.PostAsync(fullrequest, payLoad))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data has been Inserted to database", "Information", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    await RefreshDatagridTable();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Data has not been Inserted to database! {response.StatusCode}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                }
            }
        }
```

***Update 3:***

I managed to be able to insert data into the database using the InsertData function with Windows form now. However, when I try to run through the web browser and type the URL 'urlpath:Port/api/Main/InsertData?insertcolumns=(column1=value1)(column2=value2)(column3=value3)' it always comes back to HTTP Code error 405. How can I resolve this to be able to use a web browser (if needed) to insert data into the database?

Comment: Is you CORS-setup set to allow any method?

Comment: @alapaah Where would I need to set CORS-setup? (I am still new with designing Web API)

Comment: If you're running a .Net Core 7+ setup you'll do it in Program.cs

Comment: You need to provide the client code which is making a call to the api

Comment: @alapaah I added the CORS in program.cs as shown here app.UseCors(builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();
}); But, I am still getting an 405 error

Comment: why would you use url parameters with post method ?

Comment: @J.Memisevic I would like to implement this in a project with either MVC or Windows application. So, I wanted to test and see if I used the same URL with the post method using a web browser then I would feel confident that this would work if I used it in another project.

Comment: U can always use Postman or Swagger. It's more flexible and commonly used practice.

Comment: @J.Memisevic I am using Swagger and it works fine. No problem, but if I use a normal URL so say to implement that in Windows form I am getting the 500 or 405 http error code all the time.

Comment: @NeoGenesis521 405 means `Method not Allowed`. It means you tried to use an HTTP method, eg PUT or GET with the `InsertData` action, that isn't supported by the controller. This has nothing to do with whether MVC can work with URLs. If anything, the question's code is trying to replicate what ASP.NET Core, EF Core or Dapper already do with a few dozen lines. It contains a lot of connection leaks and . There are well established HTTP protocols for data too, like GraphQL and OData.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos So, do you advise me to use Dapper or EF if I want to implement this?